# They want paint by numbers. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

> Everybody wants the copy-and-paste templates. **They want paint by
>   numbers.** But they also want big profits. They want scalable ad
>   campaigns that don’t quickly burn out or take tons and tons of ad
>   rotation. Sorry, you can’t have your cake and eat it too. (Sometimes
>   you can for a while, but it will fade, I promise.)

This is an excerpt from a book talking about Facebook Ads. I get the big idea of this passage but don't understand what "They want paint by numbers" means.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_by_number) for more information about the phrase.

Comment: What did google tell you about "paint by numbers"?

Comment: This quote, and the confusion around it, is a great example of why one should never switch metaphors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paint by Numbers is a technique for non artists to achieve a reasonable result in a painting exercise.

[image: Paint by Numbers image]

Each number in the painting resolves to a particular colour and the non artist just has to pick the correct colour and stay [more or less] within the lines to achieve a reasonable result.

So, in context

**Everybody wants a solution [for scalable ad campaigns] that is easy and can be achieved by a non marketing expert**

Answer (score 1):

"Paint by numbers" is a picture that is divided into regions, where each region has a number, and each number corresponds to a specific paint color; so if you are marginally competent, you end up with a correct, complete picture with little effort simply by following the rules.  In particular, you need little to no skill, critical thinking, or ability to react to changing conditions or unique situations; success is all but inevitable.  (The actual "Paint by Numbers" product is designed for young children with no prior painting experience.)

Along with "they want copy-and-paste templates", the passage means 'everybody wants an easy, guaranteed formula for success and profits.' (Which, if there was one, would soon stop working due to overuse.)